# Avg date of birth year from single table (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, average

Average date of birth from a single table where the column's date format is '01-JAN-2001'. Looking to return total count of users, and the average DOB YEAR (oracle sql)

mock table:

```
|User_ID|birth_date|
|123|01-JAN-2001|
|123|01-JAN-2001|
|123|01-JAN-2001|
```

Comment: Average date doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Better sample data is needed, and also the expected result.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: What do you mean by "average DOB YEAR"? Do you extract just the year from everyone's DOB, and then you take the average of those numbers? What if the average is not an integer - what do you want shown?

Comment: @jarlh - "average date" makes perfect sense (at least in the Oracle `date` data type, which is on a continuum - including time-of-day). Namely, the "average date" is the unique date with the property that `sum(avg_date - individual_date) = 0`. It can be calculated by subtracting a fixed date, like 2000/01/01, from all dates, taking the average of the differences, and adding it to the fixed date. The result is independent of the fixed date.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your intention is to just average the year, you can parse it to a date, extract the year and average it as a number:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(birth_date, 'dd-mon-yyyy'))
FROM   users
```

Comment: Why even bother with `TO_DATE` and extracting the year... better: `TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(birth_date, -4))`

Answer (score 0):

(Oracle 12c:) Test table and data:

```
create table dt (
  userid_ number generated always as identity ( start with 123 )
, d_ date
);

begin
  for i in 1 .. 15
  loop
    insert into dt ( d_ ) values (
      to_date ( trunc( dbms_random.value( 2446067, 2458100 ) ), 'J' )
    ) ;
   end loop;
end;
/

SQL> select userid_, to_char( d_, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) dob from dt;

   USERID_ DOB                 
---------- --------------------
       123 19-JUN-2000         
       124 06-OCT-2005         
       125 27-JAN-2012         
       126 09-JUL-2003         
       127 23-JUL-2010         
       128 07-FEB-1992         
       129 20-DEC-2002         
       130 19-MAY-2002         
       131 23-FEB-1990         
       132 26-DEC-1990         
       133 19-JUN-1999         
       134 16-DEC-1994         
       135 13-APR-2017         
       136 31-MAR-2000         
       137 23-MAY-1987
```

Query and result:

```
select 
  count(*) user_count
, trunc( avg( extract( year from d_ ) ) ) avg_dob_year
from dt ;

USER_COUNT AVG_DOB_YEAR
---------- ------------
        15         2000
```

(Not taking "days" into account, just "years").

When using the method suggested by @mathguy

> "... It can be calculated by subtracting a fixed date, like
>   2000/01/01, from all dates, taking the average of the differences, and
>   adding it to the fixed date."

... this may be a query we could start with (I'm sure it can be refined):

```
select
  count(*) usercount
, to_date( '2000/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD' ) fixeddate
, avg( differences ) difftofixed
, to_date('2000/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD' ) + avg( differences ) fixedplusdiff
, extract( year from ( to_date('2000/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD' ) + avg( differences ) ) ) dob_year
from (
  select 
    d_ - to_date( '2000/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD' ) differences
  from dt 
);

-- result
USERCOUNT  FIXEDDATE  DIFFTOFIXED  FIXEDPLUSDIFF  DOB_YEAR  
15         01-JAN-00  250.6        07-SEP-00      2000
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why you’re trying to get the average date but I think it would go something like this :

```
“SELECT COUNT(user_id), AVG(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(birth_date, 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
FROM users”
```